# HttpModule URL Rewriting - 404 error in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have created a very simple HttpModule that rewrites the incoming path to one that matches a route in MVC. ex.:

http://www.example.com/cars.html -> http://www.example.com/Home/Vehicles/3

To rewrite the path I simply use RewritePath on HttpContext.

The problem is that while it works in IIS Express, this doesn't seem to work in IIS. I can see that the URL is rewritten, but I get a 404. It seems to happen beacause instead of matching this rewritten route against the registered routes, the StaticFileHandler tries to handle the request.

So when http://www.example.com/cars.html is entered into the browser, on the IIS error page, I see the Requested URL:
http://www.example.com/Home/Vehicles/3
which is correct, but I will also see that it tries to load a physical path: X:\Project\Site\Home\Vehicles\3.

If I enter the rewritten path into the browser, the page is loaded and works as expected, so the routes are ok.

Any ideas how could I rewrite the path from my HttpModule so that the rewritten path is than matched against the registered routes in MVC? Or any ideas what could be missing? :)

Cheers
Adam

Comment: With ASP.NET routing why do you want to reinvent the wheels?

Comment: I don't want to create nothing nearly as complex as that. I've been just playing around with the RewritePath and would like to understand what am I missing.